# Why do some icons from fontawesome in mermaid work and some do not?

Tags: quarto, mermaid

In a `revealjs` `quarto` presentation file using `Rstudio`, when I do:

````
```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
    D(fa:fa-phone)-->C[fa:fa-house]
```
````

and knit the file, I get this in the output:

[image]

Why does the first icon work, and the second icon not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with adding the [Font Awesome CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) in the header,

````
---
title: FA icon & Mermaid in Quarto Revealjs
format: revealjs
include-in-header: 
  text: |
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
---

## First Slide

```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
    D(fa:fa-phone)-->C[fa:fa-house]
```


```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
    D(fa:fa-phone)-->C[fa:fa-earth-americas]
```
````

---

[image: fontawesome icon in mermaid graph in quarto revealjs presentation]

---

But note that, As showed in @Julian answer, using [`fontawesome`](https://github.com/quarto-ext/fontawesome) extension should be a preferrable choice. You just need to use a shortcode with a random icon (to enable the extension for the document during rendering time) and then hide it (either using html comment, as shown in @Julian answer or using `hidden` pandoc div).

So you can try the following also,

````
---
title: fa icons
format: revealjs
---

## First Slide

::: hidden

{{< fa thumbs-up >}}

:::


```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
    D(fa:fa-phone)-->C[fa:fa-house]
```

```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
    D(fa:fa-phone)-->C[fa:fa-earth-americas]
```
````

Comment: can you use the fa:fa-earth-americas icon? Although the example icons I chose now works with your suggestion, this specific icon does not (btw, I was not the one who downvoted :) )

Comment: `fa:fa-earth-americas icon` is working for my case. See my updated answer : )

Comment: OK, I had a typo, your first suggestion works for me fine. Unfortunately, @Julian's answer does not work for me at all

Comment: none of these two answers seem to be working for me. I'm using quarto v1.3.353, no luck with any of the examples I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 2):

I assume quarto needs it outside of mermaid for the correct implementation of the fontawesome dependencies. You can do the following:

````
---
format: revealjs
---

<!-- Initialize with any icon {{< fa thumbs-up >}} -->


```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
    D(fa:fa-phone)-->C[fa:fa-house]
```
````

Note that I used the [fontawesome extension](https://github.com/quarto-ext/fontawesome).

[image]

Comment: I installed the extension using `quarto install extension quarto-ext/fontawesome` and it still does not help :(

Comment: which `quarto` version are you using?

Comment: Version: 1.2.335

Comment: I am using ‘1.2.269’, maybe a R restart helps.

Comment: OK, I updated `quarto` and it still does not help me.

Comment: **Note: using this comment `<!-- Initialize with any icon {{< fa thumbs-up >}} -->` is a must to activate the fontawesome shortcode while rendering the document**.